# How to make size of Label very small in terms of WIDTH and HEIGHT. Python and Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, sizehint

Lets say we have a gridlayout that is 2 columns. 
We then add something like this:

```
gridLayout = GridLayout(cols = 2, orientation = "horizontal")
button = Button(text = "Hello")
label = Label(text = "World", size_hint = (.1,.1))
gridLayout.add_widget(button)
gridLayout.add_widget(label)
```

I need the 2 columns, but I pretty much want the button to have most of the screen and the label to just be a very small placeholder.

I have tried doing size_hint's on both and just not able to change the size of it.

I am using Python 2.7.x and Kivy 1.8 +

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work for me, but perhaps you need to use the width/height directly, for which you'll need to set `size_hint = (None, None)`. You might be interested even in [`texture_size`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture_size).

[image]

Just a note, if you use Kivy 1.8 or basically anything that's below the latest stable version (now 1.9.1), it's the best time to update Kivy asap.

Comment: Great, Thanks! And Ya sorry I am using version 1.9.1! Thanks again!